# После отправки файла через Telegram файл приходит битым

Tags: python, linux, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

решил реализовать возможность пользователю хранить исполняемые файлы в боте(aiogram).
Для начала я получаю файл, читаю все его биты, кодирую в base64 и записываю это в бд.
Когда пользователь просит файл я достаю base64 из базы, декодирую, записываю в файл биты и отправляю пользователю.
Проблема:
Когда я отправляю файл через метод `bot.send_document()` файл приходит битым, т.е не работает. Я проверил все этапы и на каждом этапе файл рабочий, работает даже тот файл что получился после декодирования base64 из базы, и он тоже запускается но ***отправленный файл не запускается и скорей всего является битым***.

Так же я сравнил base64 и биты при получении и при извлечении из базы, ***они одинаковые***!
Т.е я считаю что проблема не на моей стороне т.к у меня всё работает.

Вот некоторые куски кода(**python**), и библиотека для создания base64 кода:

`base64` - [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)

Функция для создания файла из base64, входные данные:

***name - имя файла***

***base - base64***

```
def write_file_bit(self, name, base):
    file = open(f'{name}', 'wb')
    base64_string = base64.b64decode(base)
    file.write(base64_string)
```

Функция для создания base64 из байтов, входные данные:

***bytes - байты полученные из файла***

```
def bytes_to_base(self, bytes):
    base64_string = base64.b64encode(bytes)
    return base64_string
```

Получение файла и добавление в базу:

```
    data = await state.get_data()
    document_id = msg.document.file_id
    file_info = await bot.get_file(document_id)
    fi = file_info.file_path
    name = msg.document.file_name
    r = requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{TOKEN}/{fi}', f'./{name}')
    bytes = r.content
    base = file_work.bytes_to_base(bytes)

    try:
        database.add_to_queue_exe(msg.from_user.id, base, name, data['name_service'])
        create_buttons(['Вернуться на главную'])
        await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, f'Программа успешно добавлена,её можно посмотреть в личном кабинете', reply_markup=greet_kb)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        create_buttons(['Вернуться на главную'])
        await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, f'Неизвесная ошибка❌ Пожалуйста сообщите администрации', reply_markup=greet_kb)
```

Получение base64 из базы, создание файла и отправка пользователю:

```
    base = database.get_base_file_user(exes[couter][3])[2:-1]
    random_name = random.randint(1,157153717531753715371)
    expansion = exes[couter][1][str(exes[couter][1]).rfind('.') + 1:]
    file_work.write_file_bit(f'{random_name}.{expansion}', base)
    await bot.send_document(user_msg.from_user.id, (exes[couter][1], f'{random_name}.{expansion}'))
    #os.remove(f'{random_name}.{expansion}')
```

Тут в конце я закомментировал строку удаления файла после создания, этот файл ***РАБОЧИЙ***

Если коротко повторю проблему, ***файл приходит не рабочим*** и проблема точно не на моей стороне.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Самое интересное - вы сравнивали отправляемый и полученный "битый" файлы? В чём было отличие?

Comment: до отправления файл запускался, после отправки файла я его скачал и попытался запустить, и он не запускался более, если отправить apk то до отправки исправно идёт установка но если скачивать то что пришло из телеге то ошибка пакета(примерно так)

Comment: Сами файлы сравните. Глазами. Размер. Содержимое.

Comment: И ещё... Вы в `write_file_bit` вообще файл не закрываете после записи?

Comment: видимо да, как то забыл. А на счёт размера и содержимого скоро посмотрю. Но просто факт есть факт, файл не запускается

Comment: файл рабочий то отправки в базу весит 16 080 байт. До отправки но при получении из базы столько же и всё ещё работает, но вот если смотреть на файл после отправки ботом(ну и после того как скачал я этот файл) он весит 24 байта!

Comment: что очень странно

Comment: Добавил строку что бы файл закрывался, не помогло. Почему то из 15,7 килобит делает 24-25 байт

Comment: 24 байта... Откройте его на просмотр в каком-нибудь вьюере/редакторе. Внутри небось имя файла, а не содержимое. Может вы как-то не так (или не то) передаёте в качестве параметров в функцию send_document?

Comment: вы правы там действительно название файла

Comment: вот же! точно я просто передаю название за место файла! Спасибо

Comment: можете оставить ответ и я поставлю вам галочку в качестве благодарности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том что в методе `send_message()` я вставил название файла где должно было быть его содержимое. Желаю всем быть более внимательным чем я :)